# Text not centering in a span in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to center-align the text in the span. Why does it only work in Chrome, but no IE?

```css
.txt {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392);
  background-image: none;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.117647);
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-image-outset: 0px;
  border-image-repeat: stretch;
  border-image-slice: 100%;
  border-image-source: none;
  border-image-width: 1;
  border-left-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.117647);
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-right-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.117647);
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-top-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.117647);
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  box-shadow: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  cursor: default;
  display: flex;
  fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  float: left;
  font-family: MetricWeb-Medium, arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 48px;
  justify-content: center;
  line-height: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 1.54688px;
  margin-left: 1.54688px;
  margin-right: 1.54688px;
  margin-top: 1.54688px;
  outline-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  outline-style: none;
  outline-width: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 35.875px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<span class="txt">2016</span>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ramseyfeng/fd5sxv27/

Comment: I can see you are using display: flex, remember this feature is only supported on IE11 and up (http://caniuse.com/#search=flex), probably that's your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the way each browser renders the left and right `padding`.

In your code you have:

```
.txt {
    padding-left: 12px;
    padding-right: 12px;
}
```

Chrome basically ignores this padding when centering the text in the small container:

[image]

But IE11 respects the padding:

[image]

The solution is to simply remove the horizontal padding:

```
.txt {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

[**Revised Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/fd5sxv27/7/)

Answer (score 2):

I made an amendment to your jsfiddle;

Your font-size will not work with the padding you've selected with the font-size. Padding-Left was causing the off-center shift from the left side. Also your box is way too small for the font-size of 16 pts.

Jsfiddle Change ver5 - Removed padding all together, keeping the same font-size, and increased width to 70px.

Jsfiddle Change ver6 - Reduced Font Size to 12px from 16 and padding left and right reduced to 3px from 6px & 12px.

https://jsfiddle.net/fd5sxv27/5/

```
.txt {
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392);
    background-image: none;
    border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.117647);
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-image-outset: 0px;
    border-image-repeat: stretch;
    border-image-slice: 100%;
    border-image-source: none;
    border-image-width: 1;
    border-left-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.117647);
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-right-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.117647);
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-top-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.117647);
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    box-shadow: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    cursor: default;
    display: flex;
    fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    float: left;
    font-family: MetricWeb-Medium, arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 48px;
    justify-content: center;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 1.54688px;
    margin-left: 1.54688px;
    margin-right: 1.54688px;
    margin-top: 1.54688px;
    outline-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    outline-style: none;
    outline-width: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 70px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fd5sxv27/6/

```
.txt {
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392);
    background-image: none;
    border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.117647);
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-image-outset: 0px;
    border-image-repeat: stretch;
    border-image-slice: 100%;
    border-image-source: none;
    border-image-width: 1;
    border-left-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.117647);
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-right-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.117647);
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-top-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.117647);
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    box-shadow: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    cursor: default;
    display: flex;
    fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    float: left;
    font-family: MetricWeb-Medium, arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 48px;
    justify-content: center;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 1.54688px;
    margin-left: 1.54688px;
    margin-right: 1.54688px;
    margin-top: 1.54688px;
    outline-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    outline-style: none;
    outline-width: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 12px;
    padding-top: 6px;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 35.875px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```